# when i'm testing a project,how should i divide my testing in to test cycles when

Tags: manual-testing

When i'm testing a project,how should i divide my testing into test cycles.
What are the things that i have to care when i'm dividing testing cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test cycle could simulate a day, a week, a month, or no time period at all. 
The ability to simulate a given period of time, however, is what makes test cycles an ideal technique for date-sensitive testing.

Exactly what happens during a test cycle depend on the technology involved. 
For example, in a traditional legacy mainframe environment a test cycle usually consists of three parts: online data entry, batch processing, 
and the verification of batch results.

First divide the project into modules, prepare estimation. Then decide the cycle accordingly